# AWS SES - why I didn't received email

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nodemailer, amazon-ses

I'm trying to implement the flow: uploading a file to S3 and then triggering a lambda to send an email with a file attached.

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var ses = new aws.SES();
var s3 = new aws.S3();

async function getS3File(bucket, key) {
  try {
    const data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }).promise();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    console.log("event: ", JSON.stringify(event));
    const fileData = await getS3File("mh-downtime-rp", "report.csv");
    const mailOptions = {
      from: "xxxx@email1.com",
      subject: "This is an email sent from a Lambda function!",
      html: `<p>You got a contact message from: <b>${event.emailAddress}</b></p>`,
      to: "yyyy@email2.com",
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: "report.csv",
          content: fileData.Body,
        },
      ],
    };

    console.log("Creating SES transporter");
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      SES: ses,
    });

    console.log("Sending email");
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log("Email sent successfully");
    callback();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Error sending email");
    callback(err);
  }
};
```

The role of lambda has permissions:

- AmazonS3FullAccess,
- AmazonSESFullAccess
- CloudWatchLogsFullAccess

In SES, I verified email addresses.

After uploading a CSV file in S3, there's no error in CloudWatch and I can see the message `Email sent successfully`, eg. the lambda is executed successfully. However, there's no email in my inbox

Did I missed something ? Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your SES account in sandbox mode? Is the front address a verified identity (or using a verified domain) in your SES account?

Comment: In addition to what @MarkB asks, is the "from" domain setup correctly with SPF and/or DKIM to allow SES to send for the domain?

Comment: Yes my next question was going to be if you had properly setup DKIM in SES.

Comment: Yes, SES is still in sandbox, I am testing SES, haven't requested to go out yet, and the front address is an verified one.